# pthread and recursively calling execvp in C

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, system

To begin I'm sorry for my english :)

I looking for a way to create a thread each time my program finds a directory, in order to call the program itself but with a new argv[2] argument (which is the current dir). I did it successfully with fork() but with pthread I've some difficulties. I don't know if I can do something like that :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <dirent.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    pthread_t  threadID[10] = {0};
    DIR * dir;
    struct dirent * entry;
    struct stat status;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);

int i = 0;
char *res;
char *tmp; 
char *file;

 if(argc != 3)
{
    printf("Usage : %s <file> <dir>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


 if(stat(argv[2],&status) == 0)
 {
    dir = opendir(argv[2]);
    file = argv[1];
 }
 else
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

while ((entry = readdir(dir))) 
{

  if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") && strcmp(entry->d_name, ".."))
{

  tmp = malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2);

  strcpy(tmp, argv[2]);
  strcat(tmp, "/");
      strcat(tmp, entry->d_name);
  stat(tmp, &status);

  if (S_ISDIR(status.st_mode))
  {     

    argv[2] = tmp; 
    pthread_create( &threadID[i], &attr, execvp(argv[0], argv), NULL);

    printf("New thread created : %d", i);
    i++;

   }
   else if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, file))
   {
        printf(" %s was found - Thread number = %d\n",tmp, i);
        break;
    }

    free(tmp);
}  



}

pthread_join( threadID[i] , &res );

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);


}
```

Actually it doesn't works :
        pthread_create( &threadID[i], &attr, execvp(argv[0], argv), NULL);

I have no runtime error, but when the file to find is in another directory, the thread is not created and so execvp(argv[0], argv) is not called...

Thank you for you help,

Simon

Comment: Your pthread_create() line should not even compile. And even if it does, it doesn't run execvp in created thread.

Comment: It is rude to remove the content of your question like that as this posts serves not only you, but also anyone who finds it by searching later on.

Comment: If you wish to dissociate this content from your account, flag this post. Please do not roll it back any more, it may help others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `execvp` from a new thread is pointless -- all functions in the `exec` family will destroy all threads in the current process and replace the whole thing with the process you're `exec`ing.

If you want to spawn off a child process, you still need to use the traditional `fork()`/`exec()` combo. Note that the child process that you fork off will generally only have one thread in it (the one that called `fork()`), so you don't need to worry too much about what your other threads are doing.

Answer (score 3):

First, this *can't possibly work*.

Think about it: `execve` system call replaces current process (and *all* threads in it) with a new process. If you had successfully created the first thread, your main thread would instantly evaporate as soon as the first thread reached `execve`.

Second, `pthread_create` requires a function pointer as the third parameter. But you are passing this expression instead: `execvp(argv[0], argv)`. What does that expression (when evaluated) do?

It replaces your current process with a new one!

You should build your code with `-Wall`, and fix all warnings.

Building your code as is results in:

```
gcc -c t.c -Wall
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:18: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pthread_attr_init’
t.c:55: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pthread_create’
t.c:70: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pthread_join’
```

That's easy to fix, just add missing `#include <pthread.h>`. After that, the compiler will tell you that you've got a problem:

```
gcc -c t.c -Wall
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:56: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/pthread.h:227: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘int’
t.c:71: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘pthread_join’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/pthread.h:244: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
```